# I cant seem to figure out this code it keeps giving me erros. I am trying to print so it shows my name age and area of the circle

Tags: python

```
my_name= ("Kevin")
my_age= int("21")
diameter=float(2.9)
pi= 3.14
area= float(pi*(2.9/2)**2)
print(area)
print=("My name is " + my_name + ". I am " +  str (my_age) + " years old. And the area of the   circle is " + (area))
```

if anyone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: You forgot to convert `area` to `str` when concatenating. Unrelated, there's no point in `float(2.9)`. `2.9` is already a float. Same goes for `float(pi*(2.9/2)**2)`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's important to remember to include the full traceback of any errors you are seeing in the text of your question, as that tells you what the problem is and where it's occurring

Comment: You should use proper string formatting, it will keep the code cleaner and simpler.

Comment: and you change the meaning of print : you assign it a value, so it's no longer the standard print function. Instead you should
```print("My name is " + my_name + ...)```

Comment: Too much functions, too much parentheses. `my_name= ("Kevin")` should be `my_name = "Kevin"`, `my_age= int("21")` should be `my_age = 21` and `diameter=float(2.9)` should be `diameter = 2.9`. Same applies to the calculation `area= float(pi*(2.9/2)**2)` should be `area = pi * (2.9 / 2) ** 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the error that you ran into but I'm assuming your interpreter threw a type conversion error. On line 7, you tried to concatenate a string and a float **(area)**. That's what's causing the error. You need to convert your area to string.

Still on line 7, you are declaring a variable called print, instead of actually printing on screen. print is a reserved word used in python to output stuff.

Get rid of the = so that it's just `print()` and not `print=()`

Besides that, I wanted to point out the following too:

1) You don't really need the brackets when declaring your variables. For instance,  `my_name = "Kevin"` will work just fine

2) It was unnecessary declaring `my_age` as string then converting it to int. Do this instead:  `my_age = 21`

3) On your line 5, you had the following:

```
area= float(pi*(2.9/2)**2)
```

Notice, this line renders the declaration of the variable **diameter** useless. You allocated memory but never used it. I also suggest that in your case, just declare the radius variable instead of diameter because the latter doesn't contribute in calculation of your area. There is absolutely no need of declaring a diameter variable, then dividing it by 2.

Taking all those into consideration, your new code should look something like this. Not far off from what you had already

```
my_name = "Kevin"
my_age = 21
radius = 1.45
pi = 3.14
area = pi * (radius**2)
print("My name is " + my_name + ". I am " + str(my_age) + " years old" +  " and the area of the circle is " + str(area))
```

You seem very new to python. All the best in you learning amigo.